# My Macbook 2011 cursor moves and clicks but won't work

Tags: macbook-pro, cursor, click

My MacBook cursor moves fine, clicks fine on the touchpad, but will not click on anything. I tried right-clicking and this works on some windows but not all. I tried powering off, doesn't work. I tried putting the machine to sleep, doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: I also connected a wireless mouse. The issue persists.

Comment: Did you try a Restart? Do you have a wired mouse to test with? If there is another user account on the Mac, does it experience the same problem?

Comment: Did you try booting into safe mode? Hold shift ile booting, release once the Apple shows up. Boot may take a much longer time.

Comment: Thank you, Steve Chamber and IconDaemon. The safe mode booting worked. The touchpad is very sensitive now. It seems to highlight everything with each stroke. Any suggestions to address that?